# Load image to fit in merged cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table that contains the file path, when the button is clicked the macro will display an image according to the url path. Here is my code (sourch : [Link](https://www.exceldemy.com/excel-vba-insert-picture-from-url/))

```
Sub Macro_1()
Dim cShape As Shape
Dim cRange As Range
Dim cColumn As Long
On Error Resume Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set xRange = ActiveSheet.Range("C5:D6, G5:H6, C8:D9, G8:H9")
For Each cell In xRange
    cName = cell
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.insert(cName).Select
    Set cShape = Selection.ShapeRange.Item(1)
    If cShape Is Nothing Then GoTo line22
    cColumn = cell.Column
    Set cRange = Cells(cell.Row, cColumn)
    With cShape
          .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
            .Height = cRange.Height - 5
            .Width = cRange.Width - 5
            .Top = cRange.Top + 2
            .Left = cRange.Left + 2
            .Placement = xlMoveAndSize

    End With
line22:
        Set cShape = Nothing
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The code works as shown in the following illustration.

[image]

But I want the image to be in all merged cells. As shown in the following picture

[image]

Please let me know if you see anything that will fix this! I'm sure it's something simple, but I've been stuck for a while on this one.

Comment: Try `Set cRange = Cells(cell.Row, cColumn).MergeArea`

Comment: You're very welcome.  Although, I think your macro can be amended.  See my answer that I posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `MergeArea` property of the Range object to return the merged range.  Your macro can amended as follows (untested) . . .

```
Sub Macro_1()
Dim cShape As Shape
Dim cRange As Range
Dim cColumn As Long
On Error Resume Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set xRange = ActiveSheet.Range("C5, G5, C8, G8")
For Each cell In xRange
    cName = cell
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(cName).Select
    Set cShape = Selection.ShapeRange.Item(1)
    If cShape Is Nothing Then GoTo line22
    cColumn = cell.Column
    Set cRange = cell.MergeArea
    With cShape
          .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
            .Height = cRange.Height - 5
            .Width = cRange.Width - 5
            .Top = cRange.Top + 2
            .Left = cRange.Left + 2
            .Placement = xlMoveAndSize

    End With
line22:
        Set cShape = Nothing
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```